# Can a state in flutter call itself?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget, that gets updated with button press events, is it viable to call the state from inside the same state on button press event? The states are a lot in number. So I want to avoid initializing too many states.

Comment: can you please elaborate? or just share a code sample on what you are trying to do?

Comment: stateful widget by definition provides powerful state management. but it depends on how you want to leverage it as well

Comment: Code isn't ready. Functionality is a statefulWidget has functions inside it.. One of the functions facilitates changes in UI. With a button the same state needs to be called, so the function implements the new UI. Am I making sense?

Comment: Yes but the states are a lot in number. So I want to avoid initializing too many states @beerstorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can call `setState((){})` inside a StatefulWidget. According to the documentation:

> Notify the framework that the internal state of this object has changed.

That means that, if you want to update any value on your `StatefulWidget`, make sure to call it inside the `setState((){})`, like this: `setState(() { _myState = newValue; });`

From what I understood, you don't want to have too many calls to the `setState((){})` function. Since you are using a button, you can do it like this:

```dart
FlatButton(
  child: Text("Tap me!"),
  onPressed: () => setState((){ tapped = true}),
 ),
```

The arrows are syntatic sugar that substitute the curly brackets. Useful when there is only one line of code.